# Retrieve ms-rest-azure authentication code with interactiveLogin method

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying to push one inputless TV screen dashboard (using chromecast) with azure authentication in nodejs ([working fine without auth so far](https://stuffandtacos.azurewebsites.net/2017/04/05/display-azure-app-logs-live-stream-on-chromecast-or-any-webpages/))

My best move (?) is using ms-rest-azure package allowing to perform initial authentication from another device with https://aka.ms/devicelogin & a code
[image]

However, is there a clean way to retrieve this code and make it available outside the console ? I can't find reference or callback.

My fallback scenario would be to intercept `process.stdout.write` but feels like dirty.

Comment: I'd recommend using [Non-Interactive Authentication](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/runtime/ms-rest-azure#non-interactive-authentication) instead.

Comment: I'm looking for end user context and getting several instances of my dashboard. or I you then refering to a deported authentication homebrew process linked with non-interactive (re-using data provided in the homebrew process) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an options object you can pass to interactiveLogin.  One option is "userCodeResponseLogger", which should be a function, eg

```
let options = {"userCodeResponseLogger":(msg)=>{ 
    console.log("I have the message",msg)
    }
}

msRestAzure.interactiveLogin(options).then((credentials) => {
    // doing authentication stuff
```

});

Note you'll still need to parse the msg to extract the code.

Comment: that's great ! just tested and correctly getting the message where I can extract the code without playing with console hook.

Answer (score 0):

had to go forward on this issue and finally ends up by intercepting `process.stdout.write` with a better implementation then mine : https://gist.github.com/pguillory/729616/32aa9dd5b5881f6f2719db835424a7cb96dfdfd6

```
function auth() {

  hook_stdout(function(std) {
      var matches = / the code (.*) to /.exec(std);
      if(matches !== null && matches.length >=2) {
          var code = matches[1];
          // doing something with the code
          unhook();
      }
  });

  msRestAzure.interactiveLogin().then((credentials) => {
        // doing authentication stuff
  });
}
```